# RetroFit, Many to many relationships

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I have a json response that looks somewhat like this.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "user",
  "email": "generic user@gmail.com",
  "name": "harshvardhan",
  "phone_no": 2147483647,
  "created_at": "2016-06-27 12:23:25",
  "updated_at": "2016-06-27 12:23:25",
  "hash": "",
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": 37,
      "title": "aspernatur-et-rem-quos-eius-voluptatem-eveniet-aut",
      "descr": "33",
      "identifier": "5771545383a2d",
      "no_of_members": 0,
      "created_at": "2016-06-27 21:59:07",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "grp_id": 37,
        "roles": "admin"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 67,
      "title": "quibusdam-voluptas-non-facere-nihil",
      "descr": "194",
      "identifier": "57715453b8d80",
      "no_of_members": 0,
      "created_at": "2016-06-27 21:59:07",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "grp_id": 67,
        "roles": "admin"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 161,
      "title": "libero-id-ipsa-beatae-aut",
      "descr": "59",
      "identifier": "5771545469db4",
      "no_of_members": 0,
      "created_at": "2016-06-27 21:59:08",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "grp_id": 161,
        "roles": "admin"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 198,
      "title": "iure-ad-sunt-id-delectus-laboriosam-quo",
      "descr": "150",
      "identifier": "57715454a9d15",
      "no_of_members": 0,
      "created_at": "2016-06-27 21:59:08",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "grp_id": 198,
        "roles": "admin"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a many to many relationship between users and groups. 
I am using retrofit with the GsonConverterFactory. On response, how can I parse this information into objects?

I tried making a User class , and a group class, then I put an array of groups as a member of the user class. 
But when I access User.getGroups().get(1).getID , it returns 0. 
However, User.getGroups().size() does return 4 (the correct number in this case)

How can I achieve this in retrofit?

Comment: Sounds like you're just not parsing it appropriately with GSON.  The groups are getting added to the Users, but the ID isn't there. Otherwise you'd get a NullPointerException.

Comment: thanks a lot. Changing from capital ID to lower case (so now its 'id' ), fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

A practical tool to parse JSON correctly with retrofit can be to generate the classes with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org
You just have to put the example JSON, the resource type in JSON and put the desired annotation style (GSON, Jackson, ..).
Finally click on the preview button and you can see the results